# How do I bring a CDockablePane which is docked into a tab to the front

Tags: mfc-feature-pack

I have an MFC application (which is using the feature pack), it has multiple classes which inherit from CDockablePane that can be docked around the application, my application much like visual studio has docked multiple of these panes to a tabbed area at the botton.

Output | Error List | Watch | Thread

etc...

However on some event I would like to bring "Watch" to the front of that tabbed document so that its contents is visible.

Does anyone know how I do that, bearing in mind that "Watch" may also be docked on a side on its own, but also maybe floating

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this as the active tab, and the easiest way to do that is using the ShowPane() method:

```
m_MyPane.ShowPane(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE);
```

The last parameter is "bActivate".